# Jumping rope aka Skipping

Tags: weight-loss

I weigh 235 pounds I:e. 107 Kgs. I have started jumping rope for 30 minutes, few exercises for 10 ‘minutes and then 1 hour 6km walk I.e. approximately 4 mile walk per hour. Is this good workout??? I’m not interested in going to gym. I’m at the beginner’s level in jumping rope. So I’m hardly able to do 15 jumps continuously. I am feeling a lot of pain in legs but it isn’t unbearable. My knee is perfect. So just to be on safe side I wanted to know if I should keep following this workout? Although after workout it feels like there’s no legs sometimes. It pains but I am now moving with a motto No pain no gain. It is my humble request please do tell me the honest replies. Thank you!

Comment: Is your goal only weight loss?

Comment: Where in your legs are you feeling the pain? Upper legs or lower legs?

Comment: Yes only weight loss. Pain is in both thighs and calf part of the leg.

Answer (score 2):

Are you obese or normal/slightly overweight? Jump rope causes a sudden impact on joints which should be avoided in excess as it takes longer to adjust than for muscles to grow. Walking is good to allow better blood flow, move joints and improve metabolism. I would still suggest that you do about 40 minutes of bodyweight training instead of only 10 but on about every second day only. This should help you build muscles (instead of losing them because of a caloric deficit) and increase calories burned while resting.

Comment: I’m 182 centimetres in height. I have a belly fat but doesn’t look that much because of my height but overall I do look unfit and my main focus is on losing weight without going to gym as I don’t have time for gym but I am doing the routine for past five days, wake up at 4:45 AM and generally work out from 5:00-6:50 AM. So this is what I’m doing. Do suggest me what should I do. But I will like to keep skipping as part of my workout. Thank you for your time:)

Comment: Keep it. Just dont overdo it by starting too fast, rope skipping is a great exercise.